# Organising classes in a JavaScript game

Tags: javascript, organization, class-diagram

I need some help working out the class hierarchy for a game I'm developing with JavaScript. The game is a top-down space shooter with (at its basic level) a background, player, bullets and enemies.

I've come up with a class diagram which I think needs to be improved on:
[image: Class diagram]

Nothing out of the ordinary here, the main class is called Cosmos (the name of the game) which has a `tick()` method which fires at roughly 60 times per second. The `Background`, `Player` and `Enemy` classes belong to `Cosmos` and the `Bullet` class belongs to the `Player` class, because a `Player` "owns" `Bullet`s.

There is one major problem that comes to mind with this diagram though, and that is how I'll do collision detection between the players bullets and the enemies. I could write a method in the `Player` class to pass a bullet's `x` and `y` to `Cosmos` and do the collision detection in `Cosmos`, but that doesn't seem like the best way to do it. Would doing the collision detection in `Cosmos` be okay if I'm going for a neat, organisable approach?

Any other modifications you could make to make my life easier is also greatly appreciated.

Comment: This might be a better fit on codereview.stackexchange.com, which is dedicated to submission of working code for peer review. You might get some useful ideas on how to reorganise your hierarchy there.

Comment: There are no classes in JavaScript, only objects with prototype inheritance. See [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Inheritance_and_the_prototype_chain) for example.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your diagram seems to have some issues. You wrote:

> The Background, Player and Enemy classes belong to Cosmos and the Bullet class belongs to the Player class, because a Player "owns" Bullets."

This suggests an aggregate or composite relationship, but in your diagram you use inheritance arrows... You have `Player` extending `Bullets`, and multiple inheritance on `Cosmos`, which extends `Player`, `Background`, and `Enemy`. Also, your diagram is upside down; generally base classes go at the top.

If you want to use inheritance chains, consider something like this instead:

[image: diagram]

Comment: I wasn't sure what arrows to use as I only know the extreme basics of a class diagram, but wanted to get my point across in a visual way. Although your class diagram looks a lot better, I didn't think of separating out vectors and using a `Drawable` class. Really great help, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

The job seems way too small for worrying that much about class hierarchies.

In any case, Java-style classes is just one way of segregating code, keeping a reasonable order and appropriate comments can do virtually the same thing.

In short, just put Bullets directly below Cosmos, it is not that big a deal.

Comment: Agreed, why would Bullet(s?) extend Player anyway?

Comment: @GGG Because the Player class create the bullets I suppose, if the bullets didn't have to interact with the enemies it would seem like a reasonable place to put them.